# What is a more idiomatic way of “get or insert”?

Tags: elixir

I have some code that evaluates to a `user` by either looking up a user in ETS, or creating a struct, storing that value in ETS and returning that newly created user.

```
user = if user = Data.lookup(phone) do
  user
else 
  user = %User{phone: phone}
  Data.insert({phone, user})
  user
end
```

However, it doesn't look like the best code to me and I'm not sure how to refactor it. What is an idiomatic way to do this in Elixir?

Comment: Title could be further improved: in any case, making it as refined as relevant will ensure/allow such questions to retain usefulness.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I'm wondering what the use case is, because if you are able to create the new user just from the `phone` you could actually just return `%User{phone: phone}` without a lookup, or if the point is to ensure that ETS has the key you could just just call [`:ets.insert_new/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#insert_new-2). I assume your actual use case has some more fields?

Comment: Also, it is probably not an issue but just mentioning: the get-if-not-insert approach is not atomic and can lead to a race condition when run concurrently. I think it should be fine though if you are using a `:set` and are not assuming that the `insert` will always succeed. I'm not super familiar with ETS but couldn't find any atomic function doing this kind of atomic get-or-create out of the box...

Comment: @sabiwara, yes, the struct has more fields than just a `phone` field. Thanks for letting me know about the possible race condition. The current assumption is that different processes would be for different users, so I think we'll be okay here (possible famous last worlds :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the answer by @Daniel is perfectly correct and I most likely would go with it in production, here is another approach for the sake of diversity.

One might implement [`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html?) behaviour on `Data`, hiding all the implementation details there *and* use [`Kernel.get_in/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#get_in/2) afterward to transparently create the user if needed under the hood.

---

Also, not boolean-strict disjunction [`Kernel.||/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#%7C%7C/2) would do:

```rb
defp create_user(phone) do
  user = %User{phone: phone}
  Data.insert({phone, user})
  user 
end

user = Data.lookup(phone) || create_user(phone)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely use pattern match:

```
def get_user(phone, nil) do
  user = %User{phone: phone} 
  Data.insert({phone, user})
  user
end
def get_user(phone, %User{} = user), do: user
```

Then you can call from your code:

```
user = get_user(phone, Data.lookup(phone))
```